# Create a custom taxonomy that will be used to create and filter markers in a Google Map

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, shortcode, google-maps, map

I'm trying to create a Wordpress shortcode that will output a full-width, filterable Google Map with a set of markers that will be loaded on first load (and shown or hidden depending on the filters chosen).

The thing is, I've never done / used a custom taxonomy before, and I thought that it would be a good idea to create one, I was thinking about "a class" called Marker with the attributes "latitude, longitude, title and description", but I am not sure on how to proceed in order to achieve this.

Can someone please help me on how to create this taxonomy, and then load all of it's items in Wordpress programatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the WP documentation?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use taxonomies for this?

Comment: Well, I want to store these markers in some sort of system, that is easy for the users to mantain and update. Take into account that the final users of this system will have 0 experience in programming, and they would prefer to use Wordpress's interface (they have basic experience adding Posts and stuff, for example).

Comment: @jdm2112 Yes, I have, and there is something missing. Like I said, it's the first time that I'm using this, so I'm not familiar with the procedure. And I am not 100% sure that I got the concept right. What I want to use, as far as I know, is some sort of combination between a custon taxonomy (let's call it "Markers"), and "custom fields", that will be "latitude, longitude", and so on". and I'm kinda lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Understood. I think you may need to create taxonomy first see : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy then you'll need to add custom meta fields to that taxonomy see this: https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/

Comment: I'm definitely going to take a look to these links. Thank you very much, Ahmed!

Comment: Since WP 4.4 taxonomies support custom meta info now.  No need for the old workarounds.  http://themehybrid.com/weblog/introduction-to-wordpress-term-meta

Comment: Please void my previous comment, WP now supports add/update_term_meta and get_term_meta, see my updated answer with fully working example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fully working example to get you started.

#### Register the "marker" taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy( 'marker',
    'post',
    array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'label'                 => __( 'Markers', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => array(
                'name'              => __( 'Markers', 'textdomain' ),
                'singular_name'     => __( 'Marker', 'textdomain' ),
                'menu_name'         => _x( 'Markers', 'Admin menu name', 'textdomain' ),
                'search_items'      => __( 'Search Markers', 'textdomain' ),
                'all_items'         => __( 'All Markers', 'textdomain' ),
                'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Marker', 'textdomain' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Marker:', 'textdomain' ),
                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Marker', 'textdomain' ),
                'update_item'       => __( 'Update Marker', 'textdomain' ),
                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Marker', 'textdomain' ),
                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Marker Name', 'textdomain' )
            ),
        'rewrite'               => false,
    )
);
```

#### Now we need to add the hooks to add/save the fields we need for this taxonomy

```
add_action( 'marker_add_form_fields',   'marker_add_fields', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'marker_edit_form_fields',  'marker_edit_fields', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'created_marker',           'save_marker_meta', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_marker',            'save_marker_meta', 10, 2);
```

#### This function adds the fields to add new taxonomy screen

```
function marker_add_fields() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="latitude"><?php _e( 'Latitude' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="longitude"><?php _e( 'Longitude' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="">
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

#### This function add the fields to the edit screen of taxonomy

```
function marker_edit_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $latitude   = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'latitude', true );
    $longitude  = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'longitude', true );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="latitude"><?php _e( 'Latitude' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="<?php echo $latitude; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="longitude"><?php _e( 'Longitude' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="<?php echo $longitude; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

#### Finally, this function saves the custom field values for our new taxonomy

```
function save_marker_meta( $term_id, $tt_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['latitude'] ) && '' !== $_POST['latitude'] ){
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'latitude', $_POST['latitude'] );
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['longitude'] ) && '' !== $_POST['longitude'] ){
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'longitude', $_POST['longitude'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: God bless you, really. Upvoted and marked as solved. THANKS A LOT! :D